# how to remove the square bracket

Tags: python, regex

first thanks for taking time to review my problem.

I am trying to get web page in a list with beautifullsoup and then pass it to a dataframe.

```
# search for tbody and print each tr to a list
table_body=soup.find('tbody')
rows = table_body.find_all('tr')

res = []

for row in rows:
    cols=row.find_all('td')
    cols=[x.text.strip() 
    for x in cols]
#    print(cols)
    if row:
        res.append(row)

# transfer python list to dataframe
df_wocaps = pd.DataFrame(res, columns=["drop1", "Platz", "Vorher", "Wertpapier", "Kurs", "drop2", "Perf", "drop3", "1 Monat", "Suchanfragen", "drop4", "drop5", "drop6"])
df_wocaps.head()

# drop unused columns
df = df_wocaps.drop(['drop1', 'drop2', 'drop3', 'drop4', 'drop5', 'drop6'], axis=1)
df.head()
```

At the End it look slike this:
[dataframe picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDwtw.png)

i want to extract only the relevant information without all the html stuff and brackets. Anyone an idea how to do that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have more details to provide, edit the question rather than putting them in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Use variable "cols" instead of rows which gives you the input data

```
for row in rows:
    cols=row.find_all('td')
    cols=[x.text.strip() 
    for x in cols]
#    print(cols)
    if row:
        res.append(cols)
```